# How do I combine existing InputProps with additional InputProps in child component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have written a customized version of material-ui TextField (lets call it CustTextField1) with customized styling. I wish to develop another customization called CustTextField2 based on the styling of CustTextField1. I have applied InputProps to CustTextField1 and I want these to be used in CustTextField2 along with some additional InputProps I apply there. Here are the relevant parts of the code. The InputProps applied to CustTextField2 appear(i.e. The password eye icon) but appear to override the InputProps already set in CustTextField1. Any help on how to combine the two would be much appreciated.

```
function CustTextField1(props) {
  return (
    <TextField
      InputProps={{     
        disableUnderline: true,
        classes: {
          root: textFieldStyle.rootInputStyle,
          focused: textFieldStyle.focused,
          disabled: textFieldStyle.disabled,
          error: textFieldStyle.error
        }
      }}

      {...props}
    />
)
}
```

```
function CustTextField2(props) {
  return (
    <CustTextField1
    InputProps={{    
        endAdornment: (
                    <InputAdornment position="end">
                        <IconButton>
                            {showPassword ? <Visibility/> : <VisibilityOff/>}
                        </IconButton>
                    </InputAdornment>
                ),
          ...props.InputProps
        }
      }}

      {...props}
    />
)
}
```

I would like the InputProps styling in CustTextField1 to be combined with the additional InputProps styling in CustTextField2.

!!UPDATED!!

**Code Sandbox (Original Problem)** - https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-smoke-g8nsb

**Code Sandbox (Solution)** with sincere thanks to post from *toutpt* below - https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-mclean-9kh1r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always take care of the composition when you want to inherits.
So first you should take care of props you want to override.

In the following example CustTextField1 will take care of InputProps to add the basis and let the user override them.
But because there is the `classes` which is also an object I need to take care of it.

```js
function CustTextField1({ InputProps, ...props }) {
    const iprops = Object.assign({
        disableUnderline: true,
    }, InputProps, {
        classes: Object.assign({
            root: textFieldStyle.rootInputStyle,
            focused: textFieldStyle.focused,
            disabled: textFieldStyle.disabled,
            error: textFieldStyle.error,
        }, InputProps.classes || {})
    });
    return <TextField InputProps={iprops} {...props} />;
}
```

In your example you do not destructure the props so when you spread the props you completly override `InputProps`.

```
 InputProps={}
 {...props}
```

So if `props` contains `InputProps` you do it twice:

```
InputProps={} // the one define by CustTextField1
... 
InputProps={} // the one define by CustTextField2
```

Comment: Codesandbox example using your solution : https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-mclean-9kh1r

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you very much.

Comment: Excellent ! please validate the answer using the check button under the vote in that case ;)

Comment: Sorry. Answer validated now :)

Answer (score 3):

The Prop injection in React works similar to the how Javascript objects are being handled i.e the next matching key overrides the previous key. In the context of object what you are doing is replacing the `InputProps` with the `InputProps` coming from `this.props`. for your specific use case, you are overriding every prop by placing `{...this.props}` before combining `InputProps` in `CustTextField2`.

```
function CustTextField2(props) {
  return (
    <CustTextField1
    {...props}
    InputProps={{    
        endAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="end">
                    <IconButton>
                        {showPassword ? <Visibility/> : <VisibilityOff/>}
                    </IconButton>
                </InputAdornment>
            ),
      ...props.InputProps
    }
  }}
/>
)
}
```

this way you will pass all the props with the prop `InputProps` overridden to your liking.

Comment: This brings through the InputProps from CustTextField1 but the endAdornment does not get added. So it's my original problem but now the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring the same props twice so the last ones applied will overwrite the previous ones.  If you're already going to the trouble of creating 2 separate components, it would make more sense to just start the 2nd one from scratch without utilizing the first one.

However, I think a better solution is to use a single component and add a prop to toggle the additional configuration you want:

```
function CustTextField(props) {
  let inputProps = {
    disableUnderline: true,
    classes: {
      root: textFieldStyle.rootInputStyle,
      focused: textFieldStyle.focused,
      disabled: textFieldStyle.disabled,
      error: textFieldStyle.error
    },
    endAdornment: props.adornment ? (
      <InputAdornment position="end">
        <IconButton> {true ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}</IconButton>
      </InputAdornment>
    ) : null
  };

  return <TextField InputProps={inputProps} {...props} />;
}

....

<CustTextField adorned={true}/>
```